# Pandas fill zeros of lenght with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df, say

```
import pandas as pd
col = 'one'
d = {col : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

> df = 1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1

Now I want to replace all consecutive values of length x (here x = 1) with a value v (here v = 1). So that my new df looks like this

> 1,1,1,1, <1> , 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1

instead of

> 1,1,1,1, <0> , 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1

My approch so far is to build consecutive groups

```
def build_consecutive_groups(df: pd.DataFrame, col, newcol_appendix='_same'):
    df[col + newcol_appendix] = (df[col] != df[col].shift()).cumsum()
    return df.groupby(col + newcol_appendix, as_index=False)
```

to have another column 'one_same'

> 1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5

that gives me the subgroups. I can now use subgroup's apply to get the shape and check where the shape[0] is 1 and the value is 0 to identify the cell I want to replace with a 1. 
Then create an index-series that identifies these values, and set them in a final step to 1.

But this looks very complex and I think there must be a better way, for example using the rolling function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with `diff` then `cumsum` ,and using `groupby` + `transform` for the groups to replace the value

```
x=1
s=df.one.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.loc[s.groupby(s).transform('count')==x,'one']='v'
df
Out[193]: 
   one
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    v
5    1
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
10   1
```

Comment: I understand that `df.one.diff().ne(0).cumsum()` is just another way to create consecutive entries without using the shift operator replacing my `build_consecutive_groups` function. But could you explain what `s.groupby(s).transform('count')==x` does?

Also could you explain why you are using `df.loc[s.groupby(s).transform('count')==x,'one']='v' `
instead of using `df[s.groupby(s).transform('count')==x] = 'v'`

Comment: @cIph3r you want to assign the columns not all df that is why I am using loc

Comment: @cIph3r the transform count is to count the len of each group, if we need group len equal to x then we just slice it

Comment: this would also replace single occurances of "1": 
`0,0,0,1,0,0 ->  0,0,0,0,0,0`
how to only fill gaps with a specific value?